# Drawing a flag in Tikz!

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have some trouble with tikz. I wanted to draw a flag in Tikz - but that with minimal success. Here a sketch:
[image: Sketch]

The sketch is not how it should look like: the letters are just there so I am able to tell you what I actually wanted. The black rectangles shouldn't be there either, it should just show you the regions. It should just look like a green rectangle on a red rectangle with a star in the middle.

The letters are coordinates (in px). Here the **coordinates**:

**The flag edges:**

- N=(0, 300)
- M=(450, 0)

**The star edges:**

- A=(200, 180)
- B=(185, 135)
- C=(225, 205)
- D=(265, 135)
- E=(250, 180)

Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\definecolor{grun}{HTML}{239d48}%green - colour of the top rectangle
\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{bf0028}%red - colour of the bottom rectangle
\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{f6ec0f}%yellow - colour of the star


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[fill=grun] (0, 0) rectangle (12, 4.5);
\fill[fill=red] (0,4.5) rectangle (12, 9);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Problems:**
I don't know why definecolor don't work for "rot" and "gelb". I don't know how to define the units for tikz (so instead of using cm I could write the coordinates in px and get an result). I don't know how to draw the star.

**Bonus question:**
Is it possible to play with the scale of the done tikzpicture (so make it fill the whole page)? I thought of something like minipage? But that is not an important question, I am just curious for next Tikz projects.

Kind regards and thank you in advance!

Comment: The HTML color specifications should be upper cased (239d48 -> 239D48). You can use the `x` and `y` tikz options to specify base units. How is the star supposed to be drawn?

Comment: Thank you very much! @erik has already answered my question :-) ... but that with the big letters and x and y units helped a lot!

Comment: Do you want to draw the flag of Burkina Faso?

Comment: @PaulGaborit I've just noticed the similarity as well. But in that case the green and red parts of the flag should be reversed :-)

Comment: @fpast Yes: the green and red parts of the flag should be reversed... and the star should be _"contained within an imaginary circle equaling one-third the height of the flag."_ (cf. https://flagspot.net/flags/bf%27.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since adequate answers have already been given, I've felt free to do this picture with MetaPost.

For me it was an occasion to use some recent features of the `luamplib` package, (which gives an interface to MetaPost in LuaLaTeX). More precisely, I've made use of the `px` unit (which I didn't know of) thanks to the `\mpdim` command, and of the integration of colors defined by the `xcolor` package, via the `\mpcolor` command.

The rectangle's dimensions follow the OP's first wishes, except for the star, for which it seems that several points are missing. So I've included a star of my own.

**Edit** I've made some minor changes, for the flag to be more like Burkina-Faso's official one, the way Paul Gaborit reports in its comment on the OP's question. So the red and green parts are reversed, and the star diameter is exactly one-third of the flag's height.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib, xcolor}

\definecolor{grun}{HTML}{239D48}%green - colour of the top rectangle
\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{BF0028}%red - colour of the bottom rectangle
\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{F6eC0F}%yellow - colour of the star

\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

u := \mpdim{1px}; % Unit length

beginfig(1);
    z = u*(450, 300); path rect; rect = unitsquare xscaled x yscaled .5y;
    % Star summits (I was not able to use the OP's given coordinates)
    pair S[]; S0 = y/6*right rotated 18;    
    for i = 2 step 2 until 8: S[i] := S[i-2] rotated 72; endfor
    for i = 1 step 2 until 9:
        S[i] = whatever[S[(i-3) mod 10], S[(i+1) mod 10]] = whatever[S[i-1], S[(i+3) mod 10]];
    endfor
    % Drawings
    fill rect withcolor \mpcolor{grun}; 
    fill rect shifted (0, .5y) withcolor \mpcolor{rot};
    fill S0 for i = 1 upto 9: -- S[i] endfor -- cycle shifted .5z withcolor \mpcolor{gelb};
endfig;

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Noting that `1px=0.026458cm` you can set the units in `tikzpicture` as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.026458cm,y=0.026458cm]
```

And use `standalone` class. Now your code will be

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,snakes}

\definecolor{grun}{HTML}{239D48}
\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{BF0028}
\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{F6EC0F}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.026458cm,y=0.026458cm]
  \fill[fill=grun] (0, 0) rectangle (450,150);
  \fill[fill=rot] (0,150) rectangle (450,300);
  \node [star,fill=gelb,minimum size=113,star point height=33] at (225,150){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unlike erik's approach which needs atleast 2 compilation runs, now you compile once to get the flag and it is  up to scale filling the entire page.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `x` and `y` options and `\paperwidth` to fill up the page.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use capital letters in your `\definecolor` argument for HTML.

You can use the `geometry` package to set the page size to your desired flag size, then make the `tikzpicture` fill the whole page by using `\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]` and referencing anchors of the `current page` node. I've done this in the example below, but placed a star in the center. The points of the star may not have exactly the coordinates you listed, but you should be able to easily adjust the size to achieve what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=450pt,paperheight=300pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{grun}{HTML}{239D48}%green - colour of the top rectangle
\definecolor{rot}{HTML}{BF0028}%red - colour of the bottom rectangle
\definecolor{gelb}{HTML}{F6EC0F}%yellow - colour of the star

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[grun] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.east);
\fill[rot] (current page.west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\node [star,fill=gelb,minimum size=5cm,star point height=1.5cm] at (current page.center){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! However, in the future I suggest waiting a bit longer before accepting an answer, as the first answer may not be the best.